# Getting a very low accuracy on implementing Neural Network in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to implement ANN on a Cifar-10 dataset using keras
but for some reason I dont know I am getting only 10% accuracy ?

I have used 5 hidden layers iwth 8,16,32,64,128 neurons respectively.

[This is the link to the jupyter notebook](http://Sorry%20to%20disturb%20you,%20I%20tried%20implementing%20NN%20for%20cifar-10%20dataset%20using%20keras,%20but%20for%20somereason%20getting%20a%20very%20low%20accuracy,%20not%20217%20out%20of%202000%20correct,%20if%20you%20could%20plz%20have%20a%20look%20at%20it%20%20thks%20%20https://github.com/utkarshanand140/Cifar-10-Neural_network/blob/main/keras-cifar-10-nn.ipynb)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 8,activation = 'sigmoid' , input_dim = X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(units = 16 , activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 32 , activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 64 , activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 128 , activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 10 , activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 1000, batch_size = 500 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very normal accuracy for a such network like this. You only have Dense layers which is not sufficient for this dataset. Cifar-10 is an image dataset, so:

- Consider using CNNs
- Use 'relu' activation instead of sigmoid.
- Try to use image augmentation
- To avoid overfitting do not forget to regularize your model.

Also batch size of 500 is high. Consider using 32 - 64 - 128.